# Merge two dataframes using 2 ids and between dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to merge two dataframe using 2 ids and between two dates then save the output in a new dataframe.

Consider the below example:

```
# first_df 
FK    date          value1   value2 ... (more columns)
1     2019-01-01    50       50
1     2019-01-02    40       80
1     2019-01-03    80       20
1     2019-01-04    18       44
1     2019-01-05    120      50
1     2019-01-06    80       0
1     2019-01-10    60       65
1     2019-01-15    25       44
1     2019-01-25    20       20
2     2019-01-01    50       40
2     2019-01-02    80       45
2     2019-01-03    85       90
2     2019-01-08    100      10
2     2019-01-10    55       20
2     2019-01-15    80       150
...............................


# second_df
FK   entityId    date          percentage
1    1           2019-01-01    50
1    1           2019-01-05    80
1    2           2019-01-10    40
1    2           2019-01-15    60
1    2           2019-01-20    90
2    1           2019-01-01    48
2    2           2019-01-02    40
2    2           2019-01-08    50
2    2           2019-01-20    20
......................


# output_df
FK    entityId    date          value1            value2
1     1           2019-01-01    50% of 50 = 25    50% of 50 = 25
1     1           2019-01-02    50% of 40 = 20    50% of 80 = 40
1     1           2019-01-03    50% of 80 = 40    50% of 20 = 10
1     1           2019-01-04    50% of 18 = 9     50% of 44 = 22
1     1           2019-01-05    80% of 120 = 96   80% of 50 = 40
1     1           2019-01-06    80% of 80 = 64    80% of 0 = 0
1     1           2019-01-10    80% of 60 = 24    40% of 65 = 26
1     1           2019-01-15    80% of 25 = 15    60% of 44 = 26.4
1     1           2019-01-25    80% of 20 = 18    90% of 20 = 18
1     2           2019-01-10    40% of 60 = 24    40% of 65 = 26     # Because entityId is different, restart to iterate on first_df from 2019-01-10 using the FK: 1
1     2           2019-01-15    60% of 25 = 15    60% of 44 = 26.4  
1     2           2019-01-25    90% of 20 = 18    90% of 20 = 18
2     1           2019-01-01    48% of 50 = 24    48% of 40 = 19.2   # Use FK: 2
2     1           2019-01-02    48% of 80 = 38.4  48% of 45 = 21.6
2     1           2019-01-03    48% of 85 = 40.8  48% of 90 = 43.2
2     2           2019-01-02    40% of 80 = 32    40% of 45 = 18     # Because entityId is different, restart to iterate on first_df from 2019-01-02 using the FK: 2
2     2           2019-01-03    40% of 85 = 34    40% of 90 = 36
2     2           2019-01-08    50% of 100 = 50   50% of 10 = 5
2     2           2019-01-10    50% of 55 = 27.5  50% of 20 = 10
2     2           2019-01-15    50% of 80 = 40    50% if 150 = 75
```

My (FK, entityId) is my groupby couple. The "FK" is used to know all the values in order to apply the percentage and the "entityId" is used to check the date from **first_df** and **second_df**

The percentage is applied to all records with the same FK where my date is:
**second_df.date <= first_df.date < second_df.date_NEXT**

For instance, for my FK=1 and entityId=1, between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-04 I apply the percentage 50 (coming from second_df)

Currently I am using:

```
output_df = pd.merge_asof(first_df.sort_values('date'), second_df.sort_values('date'), by='FK',
                          on='date').sort_values('FK')
output_df[['value1', 'value2']].mul(output_df.percentage / 100, 0)
```

(which as you can see does not include the "entityId") in order to merge my first and second df.

My problem is I don't know how to change this in order to include the "entityId" column and repeat the records every time (FK, entityId) is a new couple. How would you do this ?

**EDIT 1**

Find below code to generate the dfs, as it was asked:

```
        first_data = [
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 50, 50],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2), 40, 80],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3), 80, 20],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 4), 18, 44],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5), 120, 50],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6), 80, 0],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10), 60, 65],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15), 25, 44],
        [1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 25), 20, 20],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 50, 40],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2), 80, 45],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3), 85, 90],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8), 100, 10],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10), 55, 20],
        [2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15), 80, 150],
    ]
    first_df = pd.DataFrame(first_data, columns=['FK', 'date', 'value1', 'value2'])

    second_data = [
        [1, 1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 50],
        [1, 1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 5), 80],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10), 40],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15), 60],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 20), 90],
        [1, 1, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 48],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2), 40],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8), 50],
        [1, 2, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 20), 20],
    ]
    second_df = pd.DataFrame(second_data, columns=['FK', 'entityId', 'date', 'percentage'])
```

Comment: Could you provide the code to reproduce the initial df's?

Comment: one idea is to group by and reindex your 2nd df by using the min and max values from `df['date']` and use `ffill` then you can just do a left join onto the dates instead `as_of` and specify the the keys to join on `['FK', 'date']`

Comment: @prp you can find it on my edit1

Comment: Sorry @Datanovice, not sure to understand. I was thinking as_of is similar of a left join (according to the doc). Could you please provide me with some pseudo code or even steps I need to add?